# using sed command in a loop

Tags: sed

```
#!bin/bash
file=txt.cfg
v4=45frsgf
n=24
ng=23jhjghg
for i in {1..3}
do
if ( $i == 3 );then 
    sed -i 's/host=.*/host = (\n(0x'$v4',0,'$n',0x'$ng',1,))/' $file
else
sed -i 's/host=.*/host = (\n(0x'$v4',0,'$n',0x'$ng',1,)),/' $file
done
```

On appending i get something like this in my file ..actual output

```
45frsgf,0,24,23jhjghg
45frsgf,0,24,23jhjghg,
45frsgf,0,24,23jhjghg,
```

Expecteed output:

```
45frsgf,0,24,23jhjghg,
45frsgf,0,24,23jhjghg,
45frsgf,0,24,23jhjghgif
```

i run a loop then on adding the last line it shouldnt add , and that line should come as last and not as first.

how to do it?

Comment: sed doesn't like literal newlines in substitution command... if your sed supports, use `\n` instead

Comment: You could also post sample Inputs and sample outputs too in CODE TAGS in your post and we could try to help you too on same then.

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` script consists of editing commands of the following form:

```
[address[,address]]function
```

where `function` represents a single-character command verb from the list in [Editing Commands in sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03), followed by any applicable arguments.

The command can be preceded by `<blank>` characters and/or `<semicolon>` characters. The function can be preceded by `<blank>` characters. These optional characters shall have no effect.

So essentially, `sed` scripts can be written in a single-line as

```
    [address[,address]]function;[address[,address]]function;...
```

Or in a multi-line form

```
[address[,address]]function
[address[,address]]function
...
```

The function you implemented is the substitute function of the form `s/BRE/replacement/flags` where your replacement consists of multiple lines. And `sed` is unable to interpret this as a single command. You wrote:

```
s/vtemp =.*/vtemp = (

                (0'$v',0,'$n',0x'$g',1,))/
```

but `sed` sees this as two separate commands

```
s/vtemp =.*/vtemp = (
(0'$v',0,'$n',0x'$g',1,))/
```

The first command has invalid syntax (hence the error). The second command also has invalid systax (btw. notice that I removed the leading spaces as `sed` does not interpret those!)

If you want to do a replacement with newline characters, you should use `\n` to indicate a new-line. Thus

```
s/vtemp =.*/vtemp = (\n\n                (0'$v',0,'$n',0x'$g',1,))/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "\n" to denote newlines:

```
sed -r -i 's/vtemp =.*/vtemp = (\n\n\n                (0'$v',0,'$n',0x'$g',1,))/' $file
```

And if you use double quotes for the outer quotes, you don't need the inner ones:

```
sed -r -i "s/vtemp =.*/vtemp = (\n\n\n                (0$v,0,$n,0x$g,1,))/" $file
```